# MVC: parâmetro na URL não está sendo passado para controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Estou executando a Action abaixo, mas o parâmetron "ArtigoOuCategoria" não está sendo passado para o Controller. Estou trabalhando com asp.net core 2.0.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Buscar(string ArtigoOuCategoria)
{
    ...
}
```

A chamada da Action está abaixo:

```
 <div class="card mb-4">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h4 class="card-title">Categorias</h4>
            @foreach (var item in Model.Categorias)
            {
                <a class="btn btn-light btn-sm mb-1" asp-controller="Artigo" asp-action="Buscar/@item.Descricao">@item.Descricao</a>
            }
        </div>
    </div>
```

A chamada da Action também foi feita da seguinte forma:

```
<a href="Artigo/Buscar/@item.Descricao">@item.Descricao</a>
```

Inclui as instruções de rota no arquivo startup.cs do projeto:

```
  routes.MapRoute(
          name: "buscar",
          template: "Artigo/Buscar/{ArtigoOuCategoria?}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Artigo", action = "Buscar" });
```

Comment: Sua rota está definida _antes_ da rota padrão?

Comment: Não esta, tentei mudar a ordem para ver se ocorreria alguma diferença, mas notei que não.

Comment: `ArtigoOuCategoria` está tipado na sua rota?

Comment: Não.. o parâmetro é do tipo string mas não especifiquei seu tipo na rota

Answer (score 2):

Gleison,

**Solução 1**

voce precisa colocar no metodo [FromQuery] ficando assim:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Buscar([FromQuery] string ArtigoOuCategoria)
```

{
    ...
}

Mas para funcionar voce precisa chamar assim:

```
<a href="Artigo/Buscar?ArtigoOuCategoria=@item.Descricao">@item.Descricao</a>
```

**Solução 2**

Declare seu metodo assim

```
[HttpPost("Buscar/{ArtigoOuCategoria}")] 
public async Task<IActionResult> Buscar(string ArtigoOuCategoria)
```

Comment: Olá Paulo.. Eu tentei todas as soluções que você mandou. Mas não funcionaram.
A URL da Solução 1 é a customização que eu não quero realizar. Dessa forma funciona.

Comment: so lembrando que a solucao dois, o metodo esta como Post e o nome Buscar, ou seja na API, voce precisa Chamar  "Seu Enderedo da API"/Buscar/STRING

Comment: Paulo, quando mudei o nome do parâmetro para id funcionou. Mas com o nome do parâmetro ArtigoOuCategoria não funcionou. 
Valew pelo help.

Comment: Que bom, fico feliz em ter ajudado =D

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, primeiro, para chamar essa action, ela deve ter o atributo HttpGet para acessar dessa forma com o href de um botão.

Segundo: para passar esse parâmetro para a action, use o botão da seguinte forma:

```
<a class="btn btn-light btn-sm mb-1" asp-controller="Artigo" asp-action="Buscar" asp-route-artigooucategoria="@item.Descricao">@item.Descricao</a>
```

Sua action deve estar nesse padrão:

```
[HttpGet]    
public async Task<IActionResult> Buscar([FromRoute] string ArtigoOuCategoria)
{
    ...
}
```

Fonte: [Working with forms](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/aspnet/core/mvc/views/working-with-forms?view=aspnetcore-2.1)

Comment: Fiz o teste, mas infelizmente o parâmetro continua chegando nulo.

Comment: Tire a instrução da rota na Startup.cs, isso é feito por convenção, e troque o nome do parâmetro ArtigoOuCategoria para artigoOuCategoria

Comment: Gustavo, quando mudei o nome do parâmetro para "id" funcionou. Mas com o nome do parâmetro ArtigoOuCategoria não funcionou.

Answer (score 0):

Verifique se sua rota padrão esta configurada:

```
routes.MapRoute("default", "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
```

e mude seu link para isto, usando o atributo `asp-route-`:

```
<a asp-controller="Artigo"
   asp-action="Buscar"
   asp-route-ArtigoOuCategoria="@item.Descricao">Edit</a>
```

Veja que o `ArtigoOuCategoria` apos o `asp-route` deve ser igual ao nome do parâmetro da sua, action, por isso esta chegando null para você.

**Dica**: coloque um break point no seu método **Buscar**, e no Google Crhome, aperte **crtr + swift + j**, e vá ate a aba Network, e então clique no botão para chamar a action Buscar, você verá que vai aparecer a chamada da sua action, clicando nela, você pode ir na sub-aba Headers, e verificar o que ta passando para sua action.

Comment: Cassio, quando mudei o nome do parâmetro para id funcionou. Mas com o nome do parâmetro ArtigoOuCategoria não funcionou.